# when + present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

I have recently read the sentence:

> When are you doing the practice?

If "doing" referred to the present, that sentence would not make sense. Does the present continuous refer to the future here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People often use `be + V-ing` for making plans.

> When are you doing the practice?

This is asking "you" about their plan, specifically when "you" is going to "do the practice".

> I'm practicing at 8.

That response means "I" plans to "practice" at 8. Again, this is planning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sometimes I get confused  with all the possibilities of expressing future in English: present, present continuous, going to, will.